# how to save the segmented region as a separate image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, superpixels

I have used the code which I have found in online and divided an image into several segments[image]

I want to extract green parts from the image and store them. I am able to display the segmented image separately with black mask like [image]

but I want to display and save the green small segmented region only as a separate image (like in this case 9 separate .jpg green images ) without black regions.

This is the code I have found in online

```
segmented_images = cell(1,max(max(L)));
rgb_label = repmat(L,[1 1 3]);
for k = 1:max(max(L)) %L-label matrix
    color = I;%im-Color img
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    segmented_images{k} = color; 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the representation of images in Matlab, (one pixel per array element), you could either segment the (segmented) image in terms of green values or use labeling (the code you found online resembles labeling).

I would suggest you took a look at [Image Analyst's Demo](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157-image-segmentation-tutorial)!